# Java inputting Chinese

Tags: java, swing

I come cross this [article](http://users.erols.com/eepeter/chinesecomputing/programming/java.html#input) about Chinese in Java.
At the bottom it says this:

> Inputting Chinese
>
> Java 1.2 comes with a set of classes for interacting with the
> operating system's built-in input methods. Also, as of version 1.3
> Java supports input methods that are independent of the OS. For more
> information on this, visit Sun's manual on using input methods.

There was a link there to point to ***Sun's manual on using input methods***. But that link was removed by Oracle. I am interested to know more about how to input Chinese independent with OS. Anybody knows about this?

Comment: Perhaps the link used to refer to [the equivalent of this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/imf/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're probably referring to the [Input Method Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/imf/overview.html).

There's [some examples](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/imf/) on how to use it, starting with [InputContext.selectInputMethod(Locale locale)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/im/InputContext.html#selectInputMethod-java.util.Locale-).

Comment: probably together with info about Font for (note physical v.s. logical), can by confortly tested by canDisplay(Xxx), because default Font (peers form Native Os for Java, can pretty ignores users setting for Locale) is diferent for each OS, a few times here, especially about Fonts from India